# Young adult book about the teenage son of a powerful superhero, who went to a school for superpowered kids

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

There was a book I read back in high school in either 2016 or 2017 about this teen boy who was the son of a powerful superhero. The son always wore red, he had blond hair and glasses I’m pretty sure. He went to this special school for teens with powers and everyone’s powers were color coded. The colors were like red, orange, green, blue and purple I believe. He became friends with this other boy who had green powers and could climb anything.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a perfect match to your description, but could it be [The Supes](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34822796-the-supes) by Matthew Pritt.

[image: The Supes]

> Slip Stephenson has the lamest super power of all time. His father, a world renowned Super, can turn himself invisible, but Slip has never managed to do anything more than turn himself an underwhelming shade of black.

The date matches because it was published in April 2017, and the main protagonist *Slip* has a father who is a famous hero. Hs father can turn invisible and is known as *The Sneak*.

The colours come in because superheroes are categorised into Red List, Yellow List and Green List depending on how powerful they are.

The climber is a girl named *Sugar* who is part squirrel. She can talk to squirrels and she can climb anything a squirrel can climb though she needs metal claws to do it.

But I don't recall Slip wearing red, having blonde hair of wearing glasses.

Answer (score 0):

### PS238

https://ps238.nodwick.com/comic/04172008/

...is a comic which matches the other half of your memory: Tyler is the blond-haired, red-shirted protagonist. He is a normal human, but his superhero parents have sent him to the titular *PS238*, a school for metahumans.

Unfortunately, in a complement to @JohnRennie's answer, the color coding and climbing friends are missing.